# Create a generic rest service using WCF

Tags: c#, angularjs, wcf

I'm using WCF for my server and angularjs for my client and I get the following error when I call my service :

```
GET http://localhost:1471/majsvc/RechercherUneListe/1/1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I've searched some answers on internet and it seems I have a problem of serialization.

Here is my interface declaration :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "RechercherUneListe/{id_utilisateur}/{type}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<object> RechercherUneListe(string id_utilisateur, string type);
```

And the service :

```
public List<object> RechercherUneListe(string id_utilisateur, string type)
{
    List<object> retour = new List<object>();
    try{
        int type_liste = System.Convert.ToInt32(type);
        switch(type_liste)
        {
            case MetierPD1.Constantes.ConstantesListes.LISTE_MESSAGE_RECUS:
                retour = ServicesMessagerie.RechercherLesMessagesRecus(id_utilisateur).ToList<object>();
                break;
        }
    }catch(Exception erreur)
    {
        Transverse.Helper.Exception(this.GetType() + " > " + MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), erreur);
    }
    return retour;
}
```

My call in JS :

```
this.RechercherListe = function(type, id_utilisateur){
    var uri = this.getServerUriMaj() + "RechercherUneListe/"+id_utilisateur+"/"+type;
    return $http.get(uri)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            return data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            return "";
        });
    }
```

An example of class I try to convert in object :

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable()]
public class MessageEmail
{   
    [DataMember]
    int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
}
```

SO my idea was to create only one service to get all my lists (I'm creating an application with lot of tables and datas) and passing the type of data in the parameters of the service.
My function called in the case returns a List of "MessageEmail". But as I need to have a generic object I tried to convert it to a List of Objects and returns objects.

Why my code isn't working ? Did I forget something ? Maybe I can't just convert my objects like this ?

I don't have any error on the server, it returns the right List (i've checked with the debugger), the error occurs on my javascript client.

Note : My service was working when I was returning a List of MessageEmail (without the conversion to object)

**EDIT : ** Using fiddler :

```
ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.

    Properties :
SESSION STATE: Aborted.
Response Entity Size: 512 bytes.

== FLAGS ==================
BitFlags: [ClientPipeReused, ResponseGeneratedByFiddler] 0x108
X-ABORTED-WHEN: Done
X-CLIENTIP: 127.0.0.1
X-CLIENTPORT: 2143
X-EGRESSPORT: 2149
X-FAILSESSION-WHEN: ReadingResponse
X-HOSTIP: ::1
X-PROCESSINFO: nw:1348
X-RETRYONFAILEDRECEIVE: *
X-SERVERSOCKET: REUSE ServerPipe#13*NEW*

== TIMING INFO ============
ClientConnected:    17:02:05.381
ClientBeginRequest: 17:02:06.792
GotRequestHeaders:  17:02:06.792
ClientDoneRequest:  17:02:06.792
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    17:02:07.784
FiddlerBeginRequest:    17:02:07.784
ServerGotRequest:   17:02:07.784
ServerBeginResponse:    00:00:00.000
GotResponseHeaders: 00:00:00.000
ServerDoneResponse: 17:02:07.815
ClientBeginResponse:    17:02:07.815
ClientDoneResponse: 17:02:07.815

    Overall Elapsed:    0:00:01.023

The response was buffered before delivery to the client.
```

Thank you

Comment: Does your service has any other simpler methods? Does their invocation from client side succeed? Aditionally: have you already configured WCF tracing in your service to get more detailed errors? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Did you try the request with Fiddler or Postman? Also, you don't need the Serializable attribute with DataContract.

Comment: My server has a lot of methods which returns lists. All of these are working. But I'm trying to create function more generics.

Comment: Using fiddler : ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning this article : http://benjii.me/2010/05/how-to-return-multiple-formats-with-wcf-including-xml-json-and-atom/

I added the following line :

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<MessageEmail>))]
```

And it seems to work now.